# Is it possible to tell SQLite in which position a given entry should be placed?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Suppose I have a table in SQLite and I have added to it 3 rows. Suppose now I want to add a new row, but instead of it being "appended" to the previous three (which is what would happen if I just call `INSERT INTO`), I want that new entry to be placed between the current row 1 and row 2 (for reasons of my own).

Is it possible? I couldn't find such a feature being mentioned in the [tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_insert_query.htm) [I had a look](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

And is it also possible to "update" directly an already existing row in changing the position in the table where it is placed? (by "directly" I mean a command that do this once instead of first deleting the current row and then inserting it again in the desired place using the method which would be the answer to the first question).

Comment: In the relational database there is no such thing as position of a row. If you want to track the order / rank of the rows, you need to implement business logic that will allow to manage it, e.g. add row_rank field and interface to update it.

Comment: Rows in a relational database don't have an "order". The ***only*** way to get retrieve them in a specific order is to use an `order by`.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Although it is possible (in some databases) to specify an ordering, it doesn't really make sense.  The order that rows are present in a table is not guaranteed to affect the order they are processed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish all the good comments were added as answers.

To answer your question about whether or not you can enter a record in a specific order in SQLite - No, you cannot.

When you create a table, try your best to [normalize it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Insert data one after the other. That's absolutely fine. When retrieving data, you can ask the database to give you in a particular manner. For example:

```
create table students (id int, fullname varchar(100), age int);
insert into students (id, fullname, age) values (100, 'James Sherk', 25); 
insert into students (id, fullname, age) values (1, 'Matt Brown', 44);
insert into students (id, fullname, age) values (2, 'Darla Kunich', 10);

-- get data ordered by age (youngest first)
select * from students order by age;
-- get data ordered by age descending (oldest first)
select * from students order by age desc;
-- get data ordered by age and then name
select * from students order by age, fullname;
```

Can you update a record in place? Yes, absolutely. Let's say Darla was not 10 year old but 20 year old. Let's update that data.

```
update students set age = 20 where id = 2;
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b92d1/3

Comment: thanks for the answer - and I was also asking myself why the comments written weren't added as answers since they pretty much *answer* my question!